# How to upload csv file using django project

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I am trying to create a file upload in django.

inventory.html:

I have two buttons `download_inventory` button download a csv file. I am trying to upload a file using `upload_inventory` button.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'bulkInventory' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="pad-btm form-inline">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 table-toolbar-left">
                        <button name="download_inventory" id="download_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Download Inventory</button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="file" class="btn btn-purple" name="inventory_csv" >
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button name="upload_inventory" id="upload_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa dropzone" >Upload Inventory</button>
                    </div>
                    .....
```

urls.py:

method `bulkInventory` is mapped with action `bulkInventory`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                    url(r'^$', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
                    url(r'^product.html/', views.product, name='product'),
                    url(r'^update/', views.updateSingle, name='update'),
                    url(r'^inventory/', views.bulkInventory, name='bulkInventory'),)
```

views.py:

```
def bulkInventory(request):
    api = APIMethods()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'download_inventory' in request.POST:
        api.downloadInventory()
        inv_file = open('inventory_sheet.csv', 'rb')
        response = HttpResponse(inv_file, content_type='application/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=inventory_sheet.csv"
        os.system('rm inventory_sheet.csv')
        return response

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'upload_inventory' in request.POST:
        form = forms.UploadFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print form.is_valid()
        api.saveUploadedInventory(request.FILES['inventory_csv'])    #  this method saves the content of file
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('inventory'))
```

forms.py:

```
class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    inventory_file = forms.FileField()
```

It is giving me this error:

> Traceback: File
>   "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     132.
>
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/manish/syserp/ekomerz/inventory/views.py" in bulkInventory
>     78.         api.saveUploadedInventory(request.FILES['inventory_csv']) File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py"
>   in **getitem**
>     322.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
>
> Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /product/inventory/
>   Exception Value: "'inventory_csv'"

Comment: missing <form .. enctype="multipart/form-data" ..>?

Comment: @chfw still getting same error

Comment: use 'inventory_file' as key instead of 'inventory_csv'.

Comment: If i will use inventory_file as key, How the file input element will be reference in the method?  I used it and still it is throwing same error.

Comment: UploadFile got inventory_file as key but in your html form it was named inventory_csv. to avoid this, you can do form = UploadFile() then in your html template, place this line {{ form.as_table }}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you go with `form.cleaned_data[''inventory_csv]` after `form.is_valid()`

Before that to check what you are getting print `form.cleaned_data['inventory_csv']`

Hope that wil help

Comment: inv_file = form.cleaned_data['inventory_csv'].           On doing this giving me this error:     

Exception Type: AttributeError at /product/inventory/
       Exception Value: 'UploadFile' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: that means your form is not valid

Comment: if request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        inv_file = form.cleaned_data['inventory_csv']

Comment: i did that. and it says false when i `print form.is_valid()`. I have included forms.py. How to correct the error?

Comment: Your form should work if you have uploaded the csv file from your form. and your uploaded file is not corrupt. If it doesnt work try changing the class name of the form and view.. I had same issue once and it solved me